# apache pointing to the wrong version of python on ubuntu how do I change?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I am setting up a flask application on and Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS EC2 instance and everything seemed to be working well (i.e. I could get to the webpage via the publicly available url) until I tried to import a module (e.g. numpy) and realised the apache python differs from the one I used to compile the mod_wsgi and also the one I am using

I am running apache2.

The apache2 logs show the warnings (specifically the last line shows the path hasnt changed):

```
[warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.5.
[warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[warn] mod_wsgi: Python module path '/usr/lib/python2.7/:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib$
```

I have tried to set the path in my virtual host conf (my python is located in /home/ubuntu/anaconda/bin along with all of the other libraries):

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/ubuntu/anaconda
WSGIPythonPath /home/ubuntu/anaconda

<VirtualHost *:80>
                ServerName xx-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/microblog/microblog.wsgi
                <Directory /var/www/microblog/app/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                Alias /static /var/www/microblog/app/static
                <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But I still get the warnings and the apache python path hasnt changed - where do I need to put the relevant directives to point apache at my python version and modules (e.g. scipy, numpy etc)?

Separately, could I have avoided this using virtual environments?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT #1:

I have run:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.prefix
```

To get:

```
/home/ubuntu/anaconda
```

And running ldd mod_wsgi.so with set/unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH gives the same symlink

```
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007f13ca1c1000)
```

Which is the system version of python NOT the one I want and NOT the one I compiled mod_wsgi when I ran:

```
./configure --with-python=/home/ubuntu/anaconda/bin/python2.7
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference in patch level revision doesn't usually matter and is explained in:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Python_Patch_Level_Mismatch

More important is what is the value of sys.prefix when scripts are run under mod_wsgi.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use

And what Python shared library the mod_wsgi.so file is actually using and whether you compiled it correctly to ensure it will pick up the alternate shared library.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library

If it truly isn't picking up the correct shared library, then the mismatch can be an issue and you need to recompile mod_wsgi.

Read through the documentation and perform the checks on your installation explained there and take the action described there as necessary.

Comment: Hey Graham, thanks for the above - just went through the last 2 links - and edited my question. Now not sure what to do though as I compiled mod_wsgi with the python version I wanted. Do I need to rebuild it or change the apache path? How do I change the apache path?

Comment: Did you temporarily set LD_RUN_PATH as indicated when you were rebuilding mod_wsgi so the correct library directory was embedded in mod_wsgi?

Comment: We ended up solving this by using Nginx/Gunicorn/Supervisord...